# jQuery Apple Time Machine carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-plugins, carousel

I'm looking for a jQuery carousel that mimics the Apple Time Machine functionality - but rather with two click buttons for next/prev rather than click the image or a slider like in coverflow. But the 'multiple screens' effect of TM would not be from actual top of screen/window stacked vanishing to top like in TM but on left diminishing to right-edge of screen if that makes sense.

The carousel would ideally be for vids but more probably just for screens of vids which either load actual vid on click or go to dedicated page.

Anyone know of any examples/demos?

Nearest I found is this:
[Space Gallery](http://www.eyecon.ro/spacegallery/)

But would ideally be vanishing/carouselling to right-side not the top and progressing on click of a button rather than the actual screen.

Comment: +1 for the Space Gallery. Nice one

Comment: I found [this one](http://css-tricks.com/examples/MovingBoxes/) or [this one](http://galleria.aino.se/themes/classic/). Is that similar to what you are looking for ?

Comment: @daemon_x - no, not really....bit more like this screen: http://www.alkaemia.com/images/carousel.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I found ContentFlow to be a great Javascript library for doing Cover Flow animations.  It is pretty similar to Apple's Cover Flow by default, but you will need to do some customization to make it mimic the up/down sliding of Time Machine.  It has pretty useful demos and documentation to help you through the process.

http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for this 
http://www.baijs.nl/tinycarousel/

It has worked well for me in a previous project, where the requirement was similar to yours.

Comment: That looks **nothing like** what was requested.  Perhaps you could share your modifications so he can achieve the desired effect.

Comment: I changed the source code of tinycarousel a bit, so that the viewport, i.e. the portlet which displays the images, now displays images which overlap one another, something like how it is suggested here http://www.highdots.com/forums/cascading-style-sheets/4-common-methods-overlap-2-a-261086.html

And added a onclick event to play the video when an image is clicked, in a new modal window. 

I took my cue from the the alkaemia.com/images/carousel.jpg when answering the question. But yes, the effect i got was only overlap, not front to back transition, but i think that can be done using this.